# how to stop a function and check if something is visible jquery

Tags: jquery, function, visible

I've seen a way to stop a function using return false; but it hasn't been working or maybe I'm doing it incorrectly.

The point of this is to grow a tree by having the user click a certain amount of times on water or cut. But once the tree grows and the image appears, I want it to forget the previous function so it can move on. This is my code:

```js
function checkTree() {
  if (water == 1 && cut == 1) {
    seed = true;
    twig = false;
  };

  if (water > 5 || cut > 3) {
    //die window pops up
    twig = false;
  } else if ((water >= 2 && water <= 4) && (cut >= 1 && cut <= 2)) {
    $("#seed).fadeOut('slow');
        $("#twig).fadeIn('slow');
    twig = true;
  };
};

if ($("#twig").is(':visible')) {
  return;
};
```

Is there another way to stop the checkTree function or another way to see if the div is visible?

Comment: You mean `function checkTree() { if ($("#twig").is(':visible')) return;...`

Comment: oh right, i'll fix that. sorry was reading it side by side and got the lines mixed up